# Explicit example of a basis of invertibles for $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Using a topological (+linear algebra) argument, one can establish the existence of a basis spanning any square matrix using invertible matrices ( $span(GL_n (\Bbb{R}))=\mathcal{M}_n (\Bbb{R}) $). But I can't seem to find explicit constructions of such bases?

Answer (score 2):

This works for all fields (with characteristic 0 or finite characteristic). Let $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix with a 1 at the $(i,j)$-th entry and zero elsewhere. Consider the set consisting of

1. $I$,
2. $I+E_{ij}$ for any $i\ne j$,
3. $I+E_{ii}+E_{i1}+E_{1i}$ for every $i\ne 1$.

From (1) and (2), one can obtain any $E_{ij}$ with $i\ne j$. Therefore, one can further obtain from (3) any $E_{ii}$ with $i\ne1$. Subtract these $E_{ii}$s from the identity matrix in (1), one obtain also $E_{11}$. Hence every $E_{ij}$ is a linear combination of the $n^2$ matrices in (1)-(3).

Comment: Why don't simply $I + E_{i,j}$ for every $1\le i, j \le n$?

Comment: @user251257 $I+E_{ii}$ is not invertible over a field of characteristic 2. E.g. $I+E_{11}=\operatorname{diag}(2,1,\ldots,1)=\operatorname{diag}(0,1,\ldots,1)$, because $2=0$.

Comment: I see, that thing again ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Such a basis can be constructed by combining three types of matrices:

1. The $n^2 - n$ matrices that have a $1$ on the diagonal, a $1$ on a single off-diagonal element and are $0$ elsewhere.
2. The identity matrix.
3. The matrices $\mathrm{diag}(2, 1, \ldots, 1), \ldots, \mathrm{diag}(1, \ldots, 1, 2, 1)$.

More generally, one can construct many bases that only consist of invertible matrices. Simply choose a base $\{I_n, A_2, \ldots, A_{n^2}\}$ and consider the family of matrices $\{I_n, A_2 + \lambda I_n, \ldots, A_{n^2} + \lambda I_n\}$. These vectors are still a base for $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and are nonsingular if $-\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of any $A_i$.