# Can we form a basis for $2\times2$ matrix using only invertible matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In contrast, can we form a basis for $2\times2$ matrix using only non-invertible matrices?

Comment: There are four extremely trivial matrices that form a basis if you require noninvertibility.

Comment: On the other hand, the identity matrix, the matrix corresponding to the nontrivial permutation of $S_2$, and the matrices given by swapping the signs of the first rows of the former two matrices form a basis with invertible elements.

Comment: Are you talking about these four 2x2 matricies? (1000)(0100)(0010)(0001)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you're saying since linear dependence does not matter when forming basis for 2x2 matrices, we would be able to form basis for both invertible and non-invertible?

Comment: @SuhailPrasathong You are wrong. The invertible matrices do not form a vector space, so you cannot find the "basis".

Comment: Related: [Explicit example of a basis of invertibles for $n\times n$ matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1410758)

Answer (score 2):

Invertible:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Not invertible: the canonical basis, i.e.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes.

For the invertible, think about the identity matrix, and try to change the diagonal values. Alternatively, think about the matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

For the un-invertible, think about the simplest basis for the set of matrices you can possibly think of.